# Concat columns, Any ideas how to get data inline?

Tags: php, html-table, concatenation

Have a table with a list of items in each row concat together in a PHP select.

Test image of what I have at the moment.[image: Current Table]

As seen the job description, price each and quantity columns have different items concat together with a line break in between each item. The problem I have now found is that if a job description is to long it goes onto the next line mucking up being in line with the price each and quantity columns.

I have tried numerous nested tables, but all end up being to messy and spoiling the odd even CSS I have at the moment. So I keep coming back to the code below.

My select:

```
"SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`$quotedate`, '%d-%m-%Y') AS `$quotedate`, `$quoteno`, 
   `$customer`, `$contactname`, CONCAT_WS('\r\r', `$jobdescription1`, 
   `$jobdescription2`, `$jobdescription3`, `$jobdescription4`, `$jobdescription5`,
   `$jobdescription6`, `$jobdescription7`, `$jobdescription8`, `$jobdescription9`,
   `$jobdescription10`) AS `Job Description`, 
    CONCAT_WS('\r\r £', concat('£', `$priceeach1`), `$priceeach2`, `$priceeach3`, 
   `$priceeach4`, `$priceeach5`, `$priceeach6`, `$priceeach7`, `$priceeach8`, 
   `$priceeach9`, `$priceeach10`) AS `Price Each`, 
   CONCAT_WS('\r\r', `$quantity1`, `$quantity2`, `$quantity3`, `$quantity4`,
   `$quantity5`, `$quantity6`, `$quantity7`, `$quantity8`, `$quantity9`, `$quantity10`) 
   AS`Quantity`  
FROM {$table} 
WHERE `$status`=0 $search ORDER BY {$table}.`$quotedate` asc";
```

And table:

```
echo "<table id=\"quote_table\"><tr>";
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++){
$field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
echo "<th>{$field->name}</th>";
}
echo "</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
echo "<tr id=\"data\">";

foreach($row as $cell)
echo nl2br ("<td>$cell</td>");

echo "</tr>";
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I could get around this.
Thanks

**Solution**
I used a slightly modified version of bmewsing's answer.
So I used a select with no formatting. Then put it in a table with the following:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
BuildRow($row[$quotedate], $row[$quoteno], $row[$customer], $row[$contactname], 
       $row[$jobdescription1], "£" . $row[$priceeach1], $row[$quantity1]);

if($row[$jobdescription2]){ BuildRow2("", "", "", "", $row[$jobdescription2], "£" . $row[$priceeach2], $row[$quantity2]);}
if($row[$jobdescription3]){ BuildRow2("", "", "", "", $row[$jobdescription3], "£" . $row[$priceeach3], $row[$quantity3]);}
if($row[$jobdescription4]){ BuildRow2("", "", "", "", $row[$jobdescription4], "£" . $row[$priceeach4], $row[$quantity4]);}
if($row[$jobdescription5]){ BuildRow2("", "", "", "", $row[$jobdescription5], "£" . $row[$priceeach5], $row[$quantity5]);}
if($row[$jobdescription6]){ BuildRow2("", "", "", "", $row[$jobdescription6], "£" . $row[$priceeach6], $row[$quantity6]);}
if($row[$jobdescription7]){ BuildRow2("", "", "", "", $row[$jobdescription7], "£" . $row[$priceeach7], $row[$quantity7]);}
if($row[$jobdescription8]){ BuildRow2("", "", "", "", $row[$jobdescription8], "£" . $row[$priceeach8], $row[$quantity8]);}
if($row[$jobdescription9]){ BuildRow2("", "", "", "", $row[$jobdescription9], "£" . $row[$priceeach9], $row[$quantity9]);}
if($row[$jobdescription10]){ BuildRow2("", "", "", "", $row[$jobdescription10], "£" . $row[$priceeach10], $row[$quantity10]);}

}

function BuildRow($qdate, $qno, $cust, $cname, $jobdesc, $priceea, $qty){

if($qdate || $qno || $cust || $cname || $jobdesc || $priceea || $qty) {
echo "<tr class=\"top\">";
echo "<td>$qdate</td>";
echo "<td>$qno</td>";
echo "<td>$cust</td>";
echo "<td>$cname</td>";
echo "<td>$jobdesc</td>";
echo "<td>$priceea</td>";
echo "<td>$qty</td>";
echo "<tr/>";
}
}
function BuildRow2($qdate2, $qno2, $cust2, $cname2, $jobdesc2, $priceea2, $qty2){
if($qdate2 || $qno2 || $cust2 || $cname2 || $jobdesc2 || $priceea2 || $qty2) {
echo "<tr class=\"middle\">";
echo "<td>$qdate2</td>";
echo "<td>$qno2</td>";
echo "<td>$cust2</td>";
echo "<td>$cname2</td>";
echo "<td>$jobdesc2</td>";
echo "<td>$priceea2</td>";
echo "<td>$qty2</td>";
echo "<tr/>";
}
}
```

Then used jQuery to add an 'odd' or 'even' class to the middle class depending on which the previous 'top' class has.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#quote_table > tbody > tr.top:even").addClass("even");
$("#quote_table > tbody > tr.top:odd").addClass("odd");

$('.middle').each(function(){
var quote_class = $(this).prevUntil(".top").prev(".top").attr("class");
$(this).addClass(quote_class);
$(this).removeClass("top");
});
```

[image]

I then put:

```
$('tr.middle').hover(function(){
$(this).prevUntil(".top").nextUntil(".top").andSelf().prev().addClass("hover");},
function(){
$(this).prevUntil(".top").nextUntil(".top").andSelf().prev().removeClass("hover");
});

$('tr.top').hover(function(){
$(this).nextUntil(".top").andSelf().not('#add').addClass("hover");},
function(){
$(this).nextUntil(".top").andSelf().removeClass("hover");
});
```

So that each "block" would highlight when the mouse moved over part of it.

I only got the finished solution through trial and error, so there may be a better way. 
 But it works!

Comment: if there is no other line breaks, then you can use $r = explode("\n", $jobdescription) and then loop through the result for printing another table (two column and count($r) rows)

Comment: Can you edit your question to give your database schema. Having another look at this and I find your SQL to be very confusing. E.g why are you using variables for column and table names?

Comment: @bmewsing Didn't know what you meant by database schema, so added the create table I'm using onto the question. Don't know much about databases, but have heard that using spaces in the column names may not be the best idea, so know that may have to change. Good point about the variables thought it was a good idea at the time. But it seems to be working as a query?

Comment: @JAllen I can't help but think that your problems with styling this table stem from a bad mysql table design in the first place. Consider changing your table schema. For example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aed69/1/0

Comment: @bmewsing No problem, cheers for the help so far. I'll keep working on it, and work on better table design. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do formatting in your SQL query (no line breaks or concat). Select the individual attributes then build your table. A row for each description, price, qty set.

```
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++){
$field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
echo "<th>{$field->name}</th>";
}
echo "</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){

 //build date, number, customer, name and the first
 //job description, price and qty
 BuildRow($row[$quotedate], $row[$quoteno], $row[$customer], $row[$contactname], 
           $row[$jobdescription1], "£" . $row[$priceeach1], $row[$quantity1]);
 //now build a row/cells for each of the
 //additional description, price, qty in the result row.
 BuildRow("", "", "", "", $row[$jobdescription2], $row[$priceeach2], $row[$quantity2]);
 //etc...
}

function BuildRow($date, $num, $cust, $name, $descrip, $price, $qty){
 //don't build if empty
 if($date || $num || $cust || $name || $descrip || $price || $qty) {
   echo "<tr >";
   echo "<td>$date</td>";
   //etc...
   echo "</tr>";
 }
}
```

With some styling you should then be able to get it to look like a "block" for each quote.

Comment: Thanks for your help, just trying to get my head round this. I have taken out all the formatting (apart from my date format) in the select query. And have entered the table build part. But am not getting any results in the table. I have put in the other rows needed.

Comment: @JAllen `var_dump()` each row in the while loop to make sure your new query is getting results. Also note you have to use the appropriate `$row[KEY]` for you column names. The ones I have given are just an example.

Comment: OK, got it to get the results with a mysql_fetch_array instead of mysql_fetch_row. Also manually did the headers, as it came up with every mysql column field name. Just now trying to get it back into the block look. If I put a class in the <tr> tag the css even odd works, but on every individual row. I guess I would add a class to the first row of a block and another to the rest of the rows. But I can't work out where to add a class for the other (additional) rows. And also get it to match the styling (font colour and bg colour) of the 'block' it's in.

Comment: @JAllen you'll probably need 3 td classes for styling a quote block look. Cell top which has borders for left/right/top, cell bottom which has borders for left/right/bottom, and cell middle that has left/right border.

Comment: Where about's would I assign the classes in the script for the middle and bottom classes? and how would I match the block colour styling of the class "middle" and "bottom" with the "top" class. Whether it be the odd or even styling.

Comment: Ok, Im getting fairly close, I think. At the moment I have the jquery: `var quote_class = $('.top').attr('class');   $('#quote_table > tbody > tr.middle').addClass(quote_class);` to add the 'top' <tr> class to the 'middle' <tr>, whether its 'even' or 'odd'. This however adds the class of the first `top` <tr> of the table to the middle ones, when I need the previous 'top' <tr>. I have tried `var quote_class = $('.top').prev().attr('class');` in the jquery but doesn't work. If you could give any insight in how I could get the previous 'top' <tr>, would be fantastic. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get the description and amount rows the same height is to use a nested table like this:

```
<style>
    table {border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;}
    td {vertical-align: top; margin: 0; }
    .outertable td {border: 1px solid black; }
    .inner {border-right: 1px solid black; }
    .innertable td {width: 100px; border-top-style: none; border-bottom-style: none;}
    .innertable td.desc {border-left-style: none;}
    .quantity {border-right-style: none;}
</style>
<table class="outertable">
    <tr>
        <td>02-02-2013</td>
        <td>102</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td colspan="3" class="holder">
            <table class="innertable">
                <tr>
                    <td class="desc">testtesttest testtesttesttestt esttesttest</td>
                    <td class="price">$1</td>
                    <td class="quantity">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="desc">testtesttest </td>
                    <td class="price">$1</td>
                    <td class="quantity">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="desc">testtesttest esttesttest</td>
                    <td class="price">$1</td>
                    <td class="quantity">1</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>02-02-2013</td>
        <td>102</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td colspan="3" class="holder">
            <table class="innertable">
                <tr>
                    <td class="desc">testtesttest testtesttesttestt esttesttest</td>
                    <td class="price">$1</td>
                    <td class="quantity">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="desc">testtesttest </td>
                    <td class="price">$1</td>
                    <td class="quantity">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="desc">testtesttest esttesttest</td>
                    <td class="price">$1</td>
                    <td class="quantity">1</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/4tJyq/ for a working sample.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a collapsable style for the job description ? you can show for example the first 50 chars, and allow the end user to click to see the full text.

take a look on this reference : http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse

cheers.